# Minimal example: Keras functional API & multi-input/multi-output regression

Tags: keras, regression, multi-output, functional-api

**Problem:**

I have a regression problem, where I want to predict two or more numerical outcomes $y_i$ based on a number of numerical features $X_i$. The model would look like: $$y_{1,i}, y_{2,i} = \beta X_i + u_i.$$

I understand that the Keras functional API could be used to solve a problem like this. In an NN setting I would use ordinary densely connected layers to solve the problem. However, I have no experiance with the functional API and I'm not sure if the problem can be solved (at all) using the functional API.

**Question:**

Can someone point me to a full-fledged minimal example on how to use the functional API for multi-input/multi-output regression as outlined above? Ideally, I'm looking for something like the code examples provided for more basic problems as described in "[Deep learning with R](https://jjallaire.github.io/deep-learning-with-r-notebooks/notebooks/3.6-predicting-house-prices.nb.html)" (code can be Python or R as I work with both).

Any additional comments on model/method choice are highly appreciated as well. However, please note that I don't want to estimate/train individual models for each outcome $y_i$, I really aim at predicting all outcomes in one model.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible solution:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from keras.datasets import boston_housing
(train_data, train_targets), (test_data, test_targets) =  boston_housing.load_data()

# Standardise data
mean = train_data.mean(axis=0)
train_data -= mean
std = train_data.std(axis=0)
train_data /= std
test_data -= mean
test_data /= std

# Add an additional target (just add some random noise to the original one)
import random
train_targets2 = train_targets + random.uniform(0, 0.1)
test_targets2   = test_targets + random.uniform(0, 0.1)

# https://keras.io/models/model/
from keras import models
from keras import layers
from keras.layers import Input, Dense
from keras.models import Model
from keras import regularizers
from keras.layers.normalization import BatchNormalization

# Input and model architecture
Input_1=Input(shape=(13, ))
x = Dense(1024, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.05))(Input_1)
x = Dense(512, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.05))(x)
x = Dense(256, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.05))(x)
x = Dense(128, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.05))(x)
x = Dense(8, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.05))(x)

# Outputs
out1 = Dense(1)(x)
out2 = Dense(1)(x)

# Compile/fit the model
model = Model(inputs=Input_1, outputs=[out1,out2])
model.compile(optimizer = "rmsprop", loss = 'mse')
# Add actual data here in the fit statement
model.fit(train_data, [train_targets,train_targets2], epochs=500, batch_size=4, verbose=0, validation_split=0.8)

# Predict / check type and shape
preds = np.array(model.predict(test_data))
#print(type(preds), preds.shape)
# is a 3D numpy array

# get first part of prediction (column/row/3D layer)
preds0 = preds[0,:,0]
# second part
preds1 = preds[1,:,0]

# Check MAE
from sklearn.metrics import mean_absolute_error
print(mean_absolute_error(test_targets, preds0))
print(mean_absolute_error(test_targets2, preds1))
```